# add shipping cost in paypal-express-checkout-simple

Tags: angularjs, node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have used **paypal-express-checkout-simple**. I need to add shipping charges per product and display that to paypal checkout page. Do I need to change any account setting in paypal?

I have followed https://www.npmjs.com/package/paypal-express-checkout-simple

Any help on this highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made changes in  lib/paypal-express-checkout.js file in my local node module files.

I have added **params.PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT** which was missing in function for shipping cost.

```
Paypal.prototype.setExpressCheckoutPayment = function(email, invoiceNumber, amount, totalShipCost, description, currency, returnUrl, cancelUrl, onlyPayPalUsers, callback) {
    var self = this;
    var params = self.params();
    if (email) {
        params.EMAIL = email;
    }

    params.SOLUTIONTYPE = onlyPayPalUsers === true ? 'Mark' : 'Sole';
    params.PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT = prepareNumber(amount + totalShipCost); // ***add ship cost here
    params.PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC = description;
    params.PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE = currency;
    params.PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM = invoiceNumber;
    params.PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM = invoiceNumber + '|' + params.PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT + '|' + currency;
    params.PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION = 'Sale';
    params.PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT = prepareNumber(amount);
    params.PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT = prepareNumber(totalShipCost); // ***add variable for ship cost
    params = _.extend(params, this.getItemsParams());

    params.RETURNURL = returnUrl;
    params.CANCELURL = cancelUrl;

    params.NOSHIPPING = 0;
    params.ALLOWNOTE = 1;
    params.REQCONFIRMSHIPPING = 1;
    params.METHOD = 'SetExpressCheckout';

    params = _.extend(params, this.payOptions);

    self.request(self.url, 'POST', params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
            return;
        }

        if (data.ACK === 'Success') {
            callback(null, { 
                redirectUrl: self.redirect + '?cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=commit&token=' + data.TOKEN, 
                token: data.TOKEN 
            });
            return;
        }

        callback(new Error('ACK ' + data.ACK + ': ' + data.L_LONGMESSAGE0));
    });

    return self;
};
```

And I have passed shipping cost while calling **setExpressCheckoutPayment** function from api, and that fixed my issue to show shipping cost on paypal checkout page.

Please refer https://github.com/totaljs/node-paypal-express-checkout/issues/24
also for more details.
Happy Coding.